# How do I get Azure DevOps to build debug AND release DLLs?

Tags: azure-devops, entity-framework-core, azure-pipelines

We script EntityFramework Core migrations as part of our Azure DevOps build pipelines. (The corresponding release pipeline then executes the migrations.) Our build pipelines reuse a single Task Group. Within that Task Group, we create the migrations using a PowerShell task:

```
if (("$(filePathToProjFolder)" -ne "-") -and ("$(dbcontexts)" -ne "-"))
{
  dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
  $dbcontexts = "$(dbcontexts)" -split "\|"
  foreach ($dbcontext in $dbcontexts)
  {
    dotnet ef migrations script -i -o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\migrations-$dbcontext.sql --project $(filePathToProjFolder) --context $dbcontext --no-build
  }
}
```

One pipeline works just fine, but the other in particular results in an error:

```
The specified deps.json
[C:\agents\dev\_work\237\s\<projectName>\bin\Debug\net8.0\<projectName>.deps.json] does not exist
```

Verbose logging has confirmed that the working build pipeline generates both the Release *and* Debug DLLs, but the failing build pipeline only generates the Release DLLs.

1. Can I force the migrations script to use the Release DLLs instead?
2. Why does the working pipeline generate both sets of DLLs?
3. How can I force the failing pipeline to generate both?

The build pipelines are Classic Pipelines, not YAML, but the corresponding YAML for the build task is:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cause was the `--no-build` parameter at the tail end of my `dotnet ef migrations script` command. Removing that parameter resolved the problem.

Comment: Glad that you can figure out the reason and solution of this issue. Maybe, you can accept your answer on this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.

Comment: @BrightRan-MSFT thanks for the reminder; StackOverflow makes the asker wait a couple of hours before accepting their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose having the steps for build pipeline like as below:

```yaml
jobs:
- job: build
  displayName: Build
  steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'dotnet build'
    inputs:
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy Files'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
      Contents: '**/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/**'
      TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      CleanTargetFolder: true

  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: 'drop-$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

---

If you want the pipeline to build with one configuration every time but you can set which Configuration to use when triggering (manual) the pipeline, you can set the pipeline like as below:

1. On the **Variable** tab of the pipeline definition page, enable the "**`Settable at queue time`**" option for the **`BuildConfiguration`** variable. Save the change.

   [image]
2. Then when you manually trigger the pipeline, you can update the value of **`BuildConfiguration`** variable to be either '**`Release`**' or '**`Debug`**' or any of other configurations supported in your project.

   [image]
3. Result.

   [image]

---

If you want the pipeline can build with both configurations every time, you use "[**Multi-configuration builds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#multi-job-configuration)" feature:

1. On the **Variable** tab of the pipeline definition page, set the value of **`BuildConfiguration`** variable as '**`Release,Debug`**'.

   [image]
2. On the pipeline definition page, click on the build job. Then find and enable the '**`Multi-configuration`**' option. And set the '**`Maximum number of agents`**'. Save all changes.

   [image]
3. Then whenever the build job is triggered, it will automatically generate two jobs with the same build steps: one is using '**`Release`**' as the value of **`BuildConfiguration`** variable and another one is using '**`Debug`**'.

   [image]

---

Comment: While this was not necessary to fix my problem, I appreciate knowing that this is possible. Thanks!